# Can this jQuery code snippet be shortened?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have just started using jQuery and although following code gets the job done, I have a feeling that it can be shortened.

```
var accountAddress = $(document.createElement("input")).addClass("readOnly")
        .attr("contentEditable", "false").attr("id", "d_accountAddress");

$("#customerid_c").next().next().next().append(accountAddress);
```

If it is not clear - what I'm doing is creating new input tag, assigning class and making it read-only, then positioning new input two TD's to the right of some known text.

**Update:**

This is simplified HTML that I'm modifying. The place where I add content is marked with **##1##** and **##2##**.

```
<TD id=customerid_c>
    <LABEL for=customerid>Customer</LABEL>
</TD>
<TD id=customerid_d></TD>
<TD class=ms-crm-Field-Normal>
    <LABEL>##1##</LABEL>
</TD>
<TD>##2##</TD>
```

Comment: You don't need to add `contentEditable=false`.

Comment: Is the TD field the last one in the row? If so, you can write `$('tr:has(#customerid_c) td:last-child')`

Comment: Yes, it is the last in the row. But I'd rather not count on that.

Comment: For tags, e.g. `<td>`, World Wide Web Consortium (W3C) recommends lowercase in HTML 4, and demands lowercase tags in XHTML. So generally it is good to get into the habit of using lowercase everywhere.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

Yes, it can.

```
$('#customerid_c').nextAll().eq(2)
    .append('<input class="readOnly" id="d_accountAddress" />');
```

In jQuery 1.4.2, you can write

```
$('#customerid_c~:eq(2)')
    .append('<input class="readOnly" id="d_accountAddress" />');
```

This selector, which does not work correctly in earlier versions of jQuery, uses the [Next Siblings Selector (`~`)](http://api.jquery.com/next-siblings-selector/) to select all sibling elements following `#customerid_c`, then uses the [`:eq`](http://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/) selector to select the third (zero-based) element matched by the other selector.

jQuery has a [large variety of selectors](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/) that can probably replace the indexed sibling. If you show us your HTML, we can find you one.

#### Other notes:

You can set multiple attributes in one call:

```
$(something).attr({ id: 'd_accountAddress', type: 'text' });
```

Comment: I've never seen that syntax before, what does `#el~:eq(2)` specifically do?

Comment: I think that the ~ is used to navigate to the children of an element, in this case #customerid_c, and eq is the equality operator, in this case used to go to the 0 based index, so the third child.

Comment: A cleaner way to write it would be. 
$('#customerid_c').nextAll().eq(2).append('<input class="readOnly" id="d_accountAddress" />');

Comment: @Tatu, @used, @Kieron, @mmcgrail: That selector does work in 1.4.2.  SO uses 1.3.2, which apparently has a bug.

Comment: @Kieron > is child elements, ~ is siblings

Comment: @petersendidit - please post this as an answer, for the googler's sake.

Comment: @SLaks i might open a new thread but i have a query related to selectors itself. Please answer or give me a link to answer. I want to know how can we select Elements of ASP.Net Auto Generated IDs. i know i can check for the endwith myID but then in grids or list items they are same. so how to do it a cleaner way...

Comment: @Shekhar: You can't.  (Unless you hard-code the full ID, perhaps using server-side inline code)

Comment: oh! i was expecting for some workaround in jQuery itself... thanx for your time..