# Why doesn't combining has() and gt() work in some cases?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I wanted to select any ul which contains more than 3 lis.

This code worked with the 1.2.6 jQuery library:

```
$("ul:has(li:gt(2))")  
.each( function() {  
$(this).css("border", "solid red 1px");  
});
```

But not 1.3.2 or 1.4.2.

This code worked with the 1.4.2 jQuery library:

```
$('ul').has('li:nth-child(3)').css('border', 'solid red 1px');
```

But not v1.2.6.

It's my understanding that jQuery version changes should (generally) not necessitate code changes.  Any help understanding this, or differences to be aware of between different versions of the jQuery libraries, would be much appreciated.  Thanks!

Clarification:
Why does each version work with one library version, but not the other?  Is this a known bug (if so, which one?), or am I doing something wrong?  Do documented bugs exist describing these issues on the jQuery site?  Should I report the 1.4.2 behavior as a bug?

Comment: Accepting the current answer for now, but I would love to know if what I saw was a known bug.

Comment: Why don't you report it?

Comment: @SLaks @KatieK I've created a ticket http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/8303

Comment: Now let's see what happens to it.

Comment: @Sime - Oh, wow, thanks!

@SLaks - I don't feel nearly confident that what I'm doing is correct and not a mistake to write a bug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is called a bug.

I found a similar one [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2492271/can-this-jquery-code-snippet-be-shortened/2492284#2492284).